# Boost "destructor is not virtual" error in MSVC 11

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, boost, 64-bit

I am trying to compile a program with boost 1.57.0 using MSVC 11.0 and I get the following error:

```
z:\d\dev\boost_1_57_0\boost\exception\exception.hpp(171) : error C4265: 'boost::exception_detail::error_info_container' but destructor is not virtual instances of this class may not be destructed correctly
```

Is there anything I can do about it?

These posts didn't seem to offer a solution

- http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-exception-detail-error-info-base-does-not-have-virtual-destructor-td3384903.html
- http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Re-exception-warning-about-non-virtual-destructor-resolution-td4554753.html

Answer (score 1):

I should've thought about this before. The error is a warning promoted to an error through `/W4`. I managed to fix it by wrapping a warning disable around the include.

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4265)
#include <boost/...>
#pragma warning(pop)
```